# LSB/MSB handling in Java

Tags: java, byte, arrays

If I have to handle values to be stored in bytes like 0x118, how do I split the LSB and MSB?

I was trying the following way... I don't think that it's the right way:

```
value = 0x118;
```

Storing in bytes...

```
result[5] = (byte) value;  
result[6] = (byte)(value << 8);  
...
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what are 'lsb' and 'msb'?

Comment: LSB - Least Significant *Bit*, MSB - Most Significant *Bit* (but Arun wants to split a short into *bytes*)

Comment: thats k.. it means Least significant bit and most significant bit

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will do it:

```
result[5] = (byte) (value & 0xFF);           // Least significant "byte"
result[6] = (byte) ((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);  // Most significant "byte"
```

I usually use bit masks - maybe they're not needed. The first line selects the lower eight bits, the second line selects the upper eight bits and shifts the bits eight bit positions to the right. This is equal to a division by 2<sup>8</sup>.

---

This is the "trick" behind:

```
  (I) LSB

  01010101 10101010        // Input
& 00000000 11111111        // First mask, 0x00FF
  -----------------
  00000000 10101010        // Result - now cast to byte

  (II) MSB

  01010101 10101010        // Input
& 11111111 00000000        // Second mask, 0xFF00
  -----------------
  01010101 00000000        // Result - 
  >>>>>>>>                 // "Shift" operation, eight positions to the right
  -----------------
  00000000 01010101        // Result - now cast to byte
```

---

To sum it up, do the following calculation:

```
 byte msb = result[6];
 byte lsb = result[5];
 int result = (msb << 8) + lsb;    // Shift the MSB bits eight positions to the left.
```

Comment: yup... it worked... if you dont mind.. can u explain me this? not really clear about it..

Comment: hey...one issue... i summed up to see if i am getting back the original value                                   System.out.println((result[5] + result[6]) + "<--LSB +MSB\n");                                                         but i am getting  25<--LSB +MSB

Comment: wow...thts a nice explanation of the logic...gettin a better insight now... :)

Comment: `0x118 = 280` - your original value is `128 = 0x80 = 00000000 10000000`

Comment: yup....you are right... thanks a lot..guess i have to do my homework of studying more about such operations... :)

Comment: one more doubt .. i am supposed to create a check sum by summing up result[1] + .. + result[5] + result[6]... can i go ahead like that or should i do like this result[1] + ... + sum of 5 & 6 as above ?

Comment: For your checksum it's adding up the bytes (normal addition, no bit shift operations)

Answer (score 10):

In today’s Java versions there is no need to do this by hand. And you shouldn’t do it as it’s easy to insert errors.

Simply use:

```
short value = 0x118;
ByteBuffer.wrap(result).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putShort(5, value);
```

for this task. The class [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)  provides methods for putting all primitive data types, in little endian or big endian byte order, as you wish. It also offers a way to put a heterogeneous sequence of values using an implied position:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(result) // default big endian, start a offset 0
  .put(byteValue).putInt(123456).putShort(value)
  .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) // change for next values
  .putInt(400).putShort(value);
```

Or a more efficient way to handle a sequence of the same kind of values:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(result).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
  .asShortBuffer().put(shortValue1).put(shortValue2).put(shortValue3);
```

Of course, you can also read back the value:

```
System.out.printf("0x%x%n",
  ByteBuffer.wrap(result).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort(5));
```