# How to round off most significant bits?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So in Java, I have:

```
long value = 1324623451867855123L
```

I need the 36 least significant bits, the MOST significant bits can be thrown out. In my head, I could use bitwise and and just do

```
long rightMost36Bits = value & 0xFFFFFFFFFL
```

And that would give me the bottom 36 bits.  But... not so worky. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Fixed typo, meant `&` for and.

**Edit2**

Really wanted bottom 10 decimal digits. So I should just use `% 10000000000`. Sorry for over engineering a solution :)

The result from that equation is **12444252435**. That is not what I want. I want more like **451867855132**

Comment: Have a look on MSB and LSB Handling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167079/lsb-msb-handling-in-java

Comment: Without calculating it, 1324623451867855123L & 0xFFFFFFFFFL could not be 451867855132... one's odd, one's even, so you've flipped the low-order bit. Consider rechecking your expected result. (EDIT: Using MS Calculator I get 12444252435) Sounds like you want MOD 1000000000000L, not AND FFFFFFFFFL

Comment: So you want the N least significant _decimal_ digits?  That's very different from your original question.

Comment: Yes N least significant decimal digits. Was willing to round up to the nearest bit length (in this case, 36).

Comment: You guys are right, put in an answer (to use mod) and I give you points... tempted to just blow up this entire question though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be value & 0xFFFFFFFFFL.  You used ^ which is XOR.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is bitwise XOR. You want

```
  value & 0xFFFFFFFFFL;
```

for bitwise AND to lose the higher order bits. XOR will leave the high-order bits alone while inverting the 36 low order bits. AND will set the high-order bits to zero and retain the low order bits.