# Multiple bitwise shifts in one statement

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a method that takes in a 32-bit int and an integer number representing a byte in the 32-bit int and return the byte passed in. i.e. getByte(0x56781234, 0); // => 0x34. My thought process is if I can rightshift the int into a position where the byte I want is the last byte of the int, I can AND it with 0xFF to get that value. So something like,

```
public int getByte(int num, int byteVal) {
    return ((num >> 8) >> byteVal) & 0xFF;
}
```

I know my logic is flawed however. I'm trying to shift multiple times in one statement. Caveat: no multiplication. Advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167079/lsb-msb-handling-in-java

Comment: The difference is I'm trying to do multiple shifts in one line. The above question accomplishes one shift of size 8.

Comment: What is the `>> 8` for? Isn't `(0x56781234 >> 0) & 0xFF` itself already returns `0x34` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to shift right by 0, 8, 16, or 24 depending on the value of byteVal. In your example, you're shifting right by 8 already even if byteVal is 0, so that's not the way.

So, how do you turn 0/1/2/3 into 0/8/16/24.... If only there's a shift operation that might be able to do that!

```
return (num >> (byteVal << 3)) & 0xFF;
```